# Switching OpenId providers (Janrain engange to something else)

Tags: openid

I've been using Janrain engange for quite a while and have been quite happy with it. 
Lately though I've a got a few reports from users which I haven't been able to really nail down. One issue was that some of the users weren't able login using google, when at the same time, I was able to login. The problem just went away misteriously. ...

Another issue I have with it, is you can't use it login users inside a JavaScript Widget on a foreign site, as you get redirected to  a new page after the successful login.

So, I'm starting to prepare myself to swith my auth provider. My main question is, how to migrate the useres credentials. In my DB I have fields which store the user id and the openId id. If I switch to a .NET libarary, would this openId Id still be usable for authentication or will I have to force through a new registration process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result:
The DotNetOpenAuth Libaray was a good choice for the migration. 
Only problem were the google accounts. For these I had to develop a migration process where I'd send the user a mail with a link and a token, so that they could authenticate themselves..